# Call a tween in tick function createjs

Tags: javascript, createjs

Trying to tween tween the alpha of a sprite on the collision of 2 other sprites

At the moment it doesn't play the tween, just jumps to an alpha of one

Is there a way of making the sprites tween to alpha of one and stay that way?

I have a feeling it's not working because the sprites function is being called continuously?

```
     function tick(){
        checkCollision();
        stage.update();
        }

      var checkCollision = function(){
       if(gameState=="gameStarted"){  
        collision = ndgmr.checkPixelCollision(car,surfaceImg,0); 
        if(collision){
            score++;
            sprites("on");
            }else{
            sprites("off"); 

            }
        }
    }


    var sprites = function(toggleParam){   
    for(var i = 0; i < spriteArr.length; i++){
        if(i == 2 || i == 3){
            if(toggleParam=="on"){
        createjs.Tween.get(spriteArr[i]).to({alpha:1}, 500);

            }else{
        createjs.Tween.get(spriteArr[i]).to({alpha:0}, 500); 

            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

solved this by setting a global var extraSpites

```
extraSpites = false;

var sprites = function(toggleParam){   
     if(!extraSpites && toggleParam == "on"){
        extraSpites = true;
        createjs.Tween.get(spriteArray[2]).to({alpha:1}, 500);
        createjs.Tween.get(spriteArray[3]).to({alpha:1}, 500); 
     return    
      }else if(extraSpites && toggleParam == "off"){
        extraSpites = false;
        createjs.Tween.get(spriteArray[2]).to({alpha:0}, 500);
        createjs.Tween.get(spriteArray[3]).to({alpha:0}, 500);
     return;    
  }
```

}